# Pass data from home.html to home.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to Ionic and I would like to know how I can pass data that is in between the `<p></p>` HTML tag to my **home.ts** file. I have tried doing `getElementById` but that doesn't seem to work. Also `ViewChild` but with zero results. I'd like to have some help concerning this question.

Comment: I'd recommend following the angular tutorial (just skip the Routing part since that's different for ionic) https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

From .ts -> html :

.ts-> `varString : String = "Hallo world";`
html-> `{{varString}}`

From html -> .ts depends of html tag

Ex. `<input type=“text” name=“username” [(ngModel)]=“username”>`
username is `username : String = "";` and it changes avry time you update the input. Similar to other html tags. You can also get elements by id or class using `Element` of ionic angular

Answer (score 0):

there is many way to pass data between html and ts, but you must have good understand about MVC design pattern. the MVC is the reason of why google introduced angular.

in angular (engine of ionic), your View(html in your project) knows everything about controller(ts file).

***** home.ts********

```
public MyName:string="jon";

 MyFunc1() 
  {
   alert(this.MyName); 
 }

 MyFunc2() 
  {
    this.MyName="other name"; 
    alert(this.MyName); 
 }
```

*****home.html*******

```
<input   type="text" [(ngModel)]="MyName"  >

<p>{{MyName}}</p>
<button ion-button (click)="MyFunc1()" >MyFunc1</button>
<button ion-button (click)="MyFunc2()" >MyFunc2</button>
```

.
.
.

if you change the value of MyName in ts, then it will change automatically in html and also if you change you input value (that it is binded to MyName) it will change the MyName value in model (in ts).

Selecting DOM in ionic isn't a right way to change models value.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the simple example of a Login page,

```
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating color="primary">Registered Email ID</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.email" name="email" type="text" #email="ngModel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"
                    required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating color="primary">Passcode</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.passcode" name="password" type="password" #password="ngModel" required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
```

The .ts code for this would be:

```
  login= { username: '', email:'', mobile:'', passcode:'' };
```

That is literally it!
You can also go about without the login object and can declare variables like

```
username: any
email: any
```

and so on; and directly reference them in the html as

```
[(ngModel)]="username"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand that when you are working on Ionic, you are working on Angular but not Core Javascript.

and here is simple example that may help

**home.html**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    name: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private alertController: AlertController) {
    }

    showName() {
        console.log(this.name);
        let alert = this.alertController.create({
            title: 'Hello ' + this.name + '!',
            buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
    }
}
```

**home.ts**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-label>{{ name }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    <button (click)="showName()">Click Me</button>
</ion-content>
```